# AngularJS - How to authenticate in first submission?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I have a login function in Angularjs, it works only when I submit it the second time. How to resolve it?

This is the code:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl',
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
    // reset login status
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        console.log('Entra '+$scope.username);
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
               AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password, $rootScope.datos.grupo);

                $location.path('/');
                console.log('Comprueba y redirecciona');

            } else {
               console.log('Falla');
               $scope.error = response.message;
               $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This console.log('Entra '+$scope.username); is happenning twice, or only on the second time? If its only the second time show us who is calling your function....

Comment: Only in the first time.

Comment: I have a $stateChangeStart event, to check the users' authentication when switching pages

Answer (score 0):

I need to make a $scope.$apply() right after changed the location and call replace() to let Angular know that things have changed.

Thank you.